# Reading each column in variables in shell

Tags: shell, variables

How can we read each item of a row in a distinct variables in shell scripting.
 if we have a line say

```
line1= 10:59 12:16 14:25 23:10
```

then how can i have

```
t1=10:59
t2=12:16
t3=14:25
t4=23:10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use read:

```
line1='10:59 12:16 14:25 23:10'
read t1 t2 t3 t4 <<< $line1

echo "[$t1] [$t2] [$t3] [$t4]"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[10:59] [12:16] [14:25] [23:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
$ line1=( 10:59 12:16 14:25 23:10 )
```

This would create an array `line1` and you can get the elements by saying:

```
$ echo "${line[0]}"
10:59
```

In order to loop through the elements of the array, you could say:

```
$ for i in "${line1[@]}"; do echo $i ; done
10:59
12:16
14:25
23:10
```